# Military time and standard time logic works but time indicator string is not working

Tags: c, struct, clock

The goal of my code was to be able to switch between standard and military time if there was a tag when executing it.

When in military time, it has to have "24" at the end, and when in standard it has to have "am" or "pm" at the end.

It seems I am able to get the ampm logic, but it shows 24 and not am or pm - only 24. Is there something wrong with the modestring in my bigger else block?

```
void show(struct tm *dateinfo, int ampm)
{
    char       timestring[9];
    char       modestring[3];
    int        hour;

    hour = dateinfo->tm_hour;

    if ( ampm == 0 )
      {

    sprintf(timestring,
            "%02d:%02d:%02d",
            hour,
            dateinfo->tm_min,
            dateinfo->tm_sec);
    sprintf(modestring, "24");

      }

    else

      {
        if ( hour < 12 )
          {
            if ( hour == 0 )
              {
                hour = 12;
              }
            sprintf(modestring, "am");
          }
        else
          {
            if ( hour == 12 )
              {
                hour = 12;
              }
            else
              {
                hour = hour % 12;
              }
            sprintf(modestring, "pm");
          }
      }

    printf("\r%s %s", timestring, modestring);
    fflush(stdout);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only setting `timestring` in the `if ( ampm == 0 )` block.  Move it to after the `if` block after setting `hour`.

```
if ( ampm == 0 )
{
    sprintf(modestring, "24");
}
else if ( hour < 12 )
{
    if ( hour == 0 )
    {
        hour = 12;
    }
    sprintf(modestring, "am");
}
else
{
    if ( hour > 12 )
    {
        hour = hour % 12;
    }
    sprintf(modestring, "pm");
}

sprintf(timestring,
        "%02d:%02d:%02d",
        hour,
        dateinfo->tm_min,
        dateinfo->tm_sec);
```

Comment: It still shows 24 for some reason, I would divide this method into 2 but my instructor wants it as one I believe

Comment: @Mochi Change the `\r` to `\n` in the last `printf`.  Each new line you write is overwriting the prior one.